# How to upgrade Xray 1.12.0 to X Ray 2.0.0 +?

Tags: jira, upgrade, jira-plugin, x-ray, jira-xray

Now we re moving Jira Zephyr to Xray. But we couldn't install X Ray 2.0.0 because of Jira 6 version.

I decided to move Xray 1.12.0 even though hasn't more features like Xray 2.0.0.

After upgrade the Jira from 6 version to 7, does any problem occur if i upgrade Xray 1.12.0 to X Ray 2.0.0 +?

Is it easy process or not?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Xray 1.x to 2.0 should be possible without problems. As precondition you need a valid license. At first JIRA should be updated. After this, you can update Xray. When finishing the update process you have to restart & reindex Jira.